# ASP.NET MVC Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

How do I achieve authorization with MVC asp.net?

Comment: Check out http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the Authorize attribute

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   //stuff
}
```

You can also use this on the controller. Can pass in users or roles too.

If you want something with a little more control, you could try something like [this](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/).

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string[] users = Users.Split(',');

            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return false;

            if (users.Length > 0 &&
                !users.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name,
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an Authorization feature with MVC, using ASP.NET MVC beta and creating the MVC project from Visual Studio, automatically adds a controller that used authorization. One thing that will help with your google search, is that it is a "filter". So try searching on "Authorization Filter MVC" and anything preview 4 or greater will help.

Comment: Ah, I was just searching "ASP.NET" "MVC" Authorization and not really finding much, thanks for letting me know to search for filters. Another problem I have when searching for MVC help is that I find stuff for previous version of the preview that aren't marked as "Preview 2" etc!

Comment: I have the same problem about the some MVC posts being not marked. I usually check the date on the post, anything more then a few months ago, I consider suspect. I am going to be doing a deep dive into MVC and blogging about it.  Do you have any requests?

Comment: Yeah sure, it would be brilliant if you attempted to complete a solution using jQuery for ajax form submissions and updates instead of standard posting to a controller and returning a view!

Feel free to post a link to your blog!

Comment: The jquery ajax thing wouldn't be that cool, actually. A controller action can return a JsonResult, directly (they don't always have to render a view), so the whole process is rather anticlimatic! :-)

Comment: Id like to see if a solution could be implemented in parallel in three modes: ASP.NET, WPF, and Silverlight. (I notice there's a "WPF Browser Application" type ... need to check that out ...)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to take a look at this article:
http://kbochevski.blogspot.com/2009/11/mvc-forms-authentication-and.html

It helped me today.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can have authentication by default:
http://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/mvc-secure-your-web-app/