# Why is the logon page is being displayed after seeding a database?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, seeding

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and have a question about being redirected to a logon page after seeding a database.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class SetupController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SetupApplication()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        applicationDbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

In the `seed` method, I am adding some objects to a different `DbContext` class, and for some reason, the `logon` page is being displayed afterwards. The `ApplicationDbContext` is for the `IdentityStore`. If I do not add any objects to the different `DbContext` class, the `logon` page is not shown.

When the `logon` page is displayed, the following `exception` is logged:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.
```

The `exception` occurs at:

```
Account\Login
```

If I comment out all of the code in the above method, except the `RedirectToAction`, the `Index` `ActionResult` is executed, and I am not required to `logon`. So I can browse to the `Index` `ActionResult` and I do not need to enter in any `logon` information. The `exception` does not occur with the code commented out.

Here is the `Index` `ActionResult`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Why would be the reason for this? What coding concept is occuring here? I do not believe I need to show code, but if needed, I will.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the attributes of your home controller , index action. is this allow anonymous as well? Do you need [custom authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770563/how-to-easily-redirect-if-not-authenticated-in-mvc-3)

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: Do you need a Authorize attribute above the [class](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute)

Comment: I have a global wide Authorize attribute.

Comment: What does `[OverrideAuthorization]` do?  Wouldn't the `[AllowAnonymous]` on it's own do the trick?

Comment: Sorry, yes it does. I have edited the post.

Comment: Is there any exception raised during the process?

Comment: An exception occurs at the logon page. I have added this to the post.