# MVC3 - Access User context in Controller base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code in a view

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

Works fine.

The same code in a custom controller base class doesn't work.  The `User` object is `null`

```
public class AdminBaseController : Controller
    {
        public AdminBaseController()
        {    
            string userId = User.Identity.Name;                
             //if(!AnAdmin)
                 //redirect to UnauthorizedPage
```

I want to use this base class in place of `System.Web.MVC.Controller` as the base for all my Administration screens.  This way I can redirect anybody that is not an admin (NTLM authentication).

Why the nulls?  How do I get to my context?  (`HttpContext` and something called `ControllerContext` are null too)

---

After some tinkering, things are null in the Controller constructors.  The Action Methods work fine.  Question still stands, but it appears I need help choosing an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Authorization filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx), [ASP.NET MVC Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329658/asp-net-mvc-authorization). Also check [Understanding Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Or you can override Initialize method on Controller, User object will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to access the 'Name'-property in a function within a controller class. That wasn't an issue and it wasn't null.

My best guess is that you can't access this object in the constructor of a controller.