# how to implement custom authorization in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, action-filter

Looking for a custom authorization solution for a asp.net mvc 3 application with sql server 2008. I dont want to use the `ASPNETDB.mdf` though.

At the moment I am trying to use a customactionfilter but I dont know how to return a boolean here. Does anyone have a good sample of a similar scenario?

```
public class CustAuthFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{

public string Roles {get;set;}
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           //return true/false based on Role the user has
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be deriving from [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) if you want to implement custom authorization.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/717312/291687) answer gives you a short example in how to use it.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // check context and roles

        ...

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually if I recall you need to ensure you call base.AuthorizeCore because of caching issues and the base handles it.