# Control access to web pages asp mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, razor, user-controls

I'm working on an **asp .net mvc 4** application. I have created a **database for users and roles** (one table for users and one other for their roles). I want to control the access to some pages. Just so you know I have **many roles** in my table (if there was only two roles this would have been easy to do). How can I do that? Is there any modification I shoud do on web.config?
- is it possible to hide a button (for example) for some users (not to hide all the view) or is it obligatory to hide all the view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329658/asp-net-mvc-authorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions like this, please see: [ASP.NET MVC Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329658/asp-net-mvc-authorization)

The Authorize attribute is still valid and works well with the UserProvider and RoleProvider.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx